# How to change search engine language?

Tags: languages, google-search

I'm a native Hungarian speaker, a few months ago I moved to Germany, and I have a problem with the Google search, I installed the Google chrome on my android device but the default search engine is German(google.de), it's so annoying when I would like to get English results, but instead of that I'm getting Germany results. How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set yor language by clicking on 'Einstellungen' or navigate directly to the english localized version: http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en to set it there (you can switch the 'hl=en' for english to hl=hu for hungarian or any other you want in the link).

Setting your start page is not what you want: This will not affect searches from the widget or from the omnibox (the auto completion, aka instant search).

Edit:
Seems like the keyboard language sets the default... switched from en to german and back.

Answer (score 0):

Your search settings are tied to the location where you first installed and ran Chrome. Currently, it's not possible to adjust the language or country domain. This is a known issue in the current version, and we are working on a fix.

As a workaround, go to Android Settings > Apps > Chrome > Clear Data to reset your location. (Note: Enable Sync first to keep your browser settings.)

Comment: For clarification, this is quoted from [JL King, one of Google Employee, from Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/exdhj8dxW2w/w8KocPDofBAJ).